# Does simpleSAMLphp support user registeration too?

Tags: php, single-sign-on, simplesamlphp

I've been looking for a decent PHP SSO solution and started using simpleSAMLphp. So far so good, really quick to install. So I have a login link and a logout link, how do I register new users from the Service Provider end. I'm hoping that simpleSAMLphp handles this, or do I need to install a module. Or do I need to implement this part myself? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I havnt tried out `simplesamlphp`.But after searching for a while i have found a module named `selfregister`.

`It contains a user interface for users to register new account. It also allows users to register some user attributes, like name, e-mail etc.`

You can check the source code [here](https://code.google.com/p/simplesamlphp-labs/source/checkout)

You can download the zip from [here](https://code.google.com/p/simplesamlphp-labs/downloads/list)